# Connect SQL Server 2005 to Access 2.0

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2005, odbc

Is it possible to connect from MS ACCESS 2.0 (16bit) to a SQL Server 2005 database (32bit) with ODBC? If it is possible how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't without an external tool that does just that, and more!

Check this out!

https://www.quest.com/products/toad-data-point/

TOAD's DATA Point is a product I've used for years and it allows me to connect to practically any database or data source via ODBC and other connection protocols.

The beauty about the product is that I can visually design and link tables from any database into one single SQL query, and it works!

Note: I am not affiliated with Toad or Quest Software. Just a happy customer.

Comment: but Access 2.0 is a 16 bit product, and that product you are talking about is x32 - then obviously thus can't work together.

Comment: But TOAD will still have to match the client software driver bit size. A 16 bit program cannot consume x32 bit software. Nor can a it consume x64 bit software. A x32 ODBC driver can connect to x32/x64 SQL server only with the correct matched drivers installed.  So while the x32 bit version of TOAD can certainly consume x16, x32, x64 from SQL server, in the case of Access you would have to install the x32 ODBC Access driver to work with TOAD x32. x32 TOAD CAN NOT consume Access x64 for example (unless you have x64 TOAD installed). Access is in-process based and you do have to match the bit size

Comment: Simply pointing out that the x32 bit version of TOAD will NOT work with Access x64. In case the boatload of brains just left the harbor without you on that boat – the context of the question was in regards to matching bit size for drivers. A client to SQL server can use either x32 or x64 bit drivers to consume that data. In the case of Access you not only have to match the bit size since it is in-process, but you can’t install both x32 and x64 bit drivers for a given version of Access at the same time – so my points stand and are most relevant to this discussion.

Comment: WFernando68,  Try again!! I said: "== can’t install both x32 and x64 bit drivers for a GIVEN version of Access at the same time ==". Did you read that? I said SAME version of Access drivers. The example workaround your link means  you use TWO DIFFERENT versions of Access. And 2007 can't open 2010 files if you use newer ACE features. So the pointed out solution in that example requires one to install two different versions of Access - and 2007 will not work with 2010 files if you use newer features.  The bottom line is you have to install the correct bit size driver and can't mix them for TOAD.